# Can gdal_calc operate conditionally with values from two tifs

Tags: gdal, gdal-calc

I am trying to correct some water table .tifs (WT) to the ground level elevation (DEM) so that water levels are not incorrectly presented as above ground. I have looked at many similar questions and answers but it seems to me that the conditional capability of gdal_calc is limited to subbing in a static floating point number. I need it to use values from a DEM in the event that the water table is above ground. Pythonically, this would be

```
if (DEM - WT) > 0:
   output = WT
else:
   output = DEM
```

However, I can only seem to get gdal_calc to sub in a static floating point number, not a reference to a more dynamic .tif file where the value would depend on the grid location.

Is this possible with gdal?  I have tried the following command line calls:

```
python "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal_calc.py" -A DEM.tif -B WT.tif --calc="B*((A-B)>0)" --outfile WT_belowGround.tif
```

This produces a .tif with values only where WT is below ground with No Data gaps where it is above ground. This is close to what I want but I want data coverage in all locations for producing contours.

```
python "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal_calc.py" -A DEM.tif -B WT.tif --calc="B*((A-B)>0)" --calc="A*((A-B)<0)" --outfile WT_aboveGround.tif
```

This produces a .tif with values only where WT is above ground with No Data gaps where it is below ground. Again, this is close to what I want but I want data coverage in all locations and it seems the second --calc call overwrites the first with No Data values.

Trying to combine both of these I have tried several things without the desired result. The most obvious thing to me is to assign the NoDataValue to the desired DEM.tif as is shown below.

```
python "C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal_calc.py" -A DEM.tif -B WT.tif --calc="B*((A-B)>0)" NoDataValue=DEM.tif --outfile diff.tif
```

While this runs and produces a .tif file, it gives an error and again, it produces a .tif with values only where WT is below ground with No Data gaps where it is above ground. The error is below

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
```

Is this something that gdal can do or do I need to find another way to approach this? One thought I have is to produce the two .tif files of WT above ground and below ground and combine them but I am not sure how to combine them either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to expressions you can use numpy functions in gdal_calc.  Sounds like you might be looking for [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Something like:

```
--calc="where((A-B)>0), A, B)"
```

Comment: That is awesome! I was not aware of this, now I think I will be investigating numpy functions to see what other gems it contains.